# Does gem 'yt' returns incorrect count videos in youtube channel?

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-ruby-client

I use **`gem "yt", '= 0.25.1'`** in my project and I face with a strange problem

related to `video_count` method ([link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yt/Yt/Models/Channel#video_count-instance_method) to docs, [link](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/blob/master/lib/yt/models/channel.rb#L197) to source) of `Channel` model.

So, method `video_count` provide a possibility to get the number of videos in channel.

(`@channel.videos_count` is faster than `@channel.videos.count`)

In case of [Simon's Cat channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE3pZOwArJXDOQjcQsiQT_w) with 17 videos it works fine:

```
Yt::Channel.new(id: 'UCE3pZOwArJXDOQjcQsiQT_w').video_count
# => 17 (correct)
Yt::Channel.new(id: 'UCE3pZOwArJXDOQjcQsiQT_w').videos.count
# => 17 (correct)
```

But, when I use channel which contain 1 or two videos ([My channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjBR9x-hg44guAAgFFzm-6w) etc.) it returns incorrect data:

```
Yt::Channel.new(id: 'UCjBR9x-hg44guAAgFFzm-6w').video_count
# => 4 (incorrect)
Yt::Channel.new(id: 'UCjBR9x-hg44guAAgFFzm-6w').videos.count
# => 2 (correct)
```

Why results is incorrect? Is it possible to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe the private or unlisted videos you have on your accound

Comment: no, cause I just create a channel and upload two videos..